# bind10 cannot automatically tranfer zone from master to slave

Tags: dns

I followed this guide to configure Zone transfer in bind10:
http://www.tokiwinter.com/bind-10-zone-transfers-tsig-and-ddns/

Everything worked ok except that It didn't automatically transfer zone from master to slave when I ran
nsupdate on master server.

It only transferred when I ran: > Xfrin retransfer example.com on slave server.

Did i miss something in configuration?

I'm using bind10 1.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a small refresh time in SOA record:

example.com. IN SOA ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. ( 2013140201
                         172800 900 1209600 3600 )

Become:

example.com. IN SOA ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. ( 2013140201
                         2 900 1209600 3600 )

So that the slave automatically send a request to transfer zone if any changes in that period of time (2 seconds).

That solved!

Thanks